# Username is repeated if the one user have shared more than one file in Django?

Tags: django, model

I have a django view which gives the shared_user_id to django template:

```
 shared_by = Share.objects.filter(shared_user_id=log_id)
```

Here's my share and user model:

```
class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True, db_index=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    #password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

I am calling in template like this:

```
{% for choice in shared_with_me %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <tr class="oddclass">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice_shard_with_me" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.file_name }}" onchange="checkChecked()"/></td>
        <td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.file_name }}</label></td>
        <td>{{ choice.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ choice.size }}</td>
        <td>{{ choice.end_date }}</td>
        {% for file in shared_by %}
            {% ifequal file.users choice.users %} 
                {% if forloop %}
                    <td>{{ file.users.username }}</td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's my coloumn name of each table in template:

File Name,  Type,   Size,   Shared On,  Shared By

In shared by, the username of the user who shared the file is shown. But for same user, username is repeated like this:
Shared With Me

```
    File Name   Type    Size       Shared On            Shared By
    ok.txt  txt 4.78 MB February 24, 2013, 09:59AM  sachitad
    ok.txt  txt 4.78 MB February 24, 2013, 10:08AM  sachitdhiifds   sachitdhiifds
    NC_008253.fna   fna 4.78 MB February 24, 2013, 10:11AMsachitdhiifds sachitdhiifds
    NC_008253.fna   fna 4.78 MB February 24, 2013, 10:20AM  hello
    ok.txt  txt 4.78 MB February 24, 2013, 10:30AM  abcde   abcde
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your set of data. I think that code: `{% for file in shared_by %}` get from database two records of file with specific user and print it twice.